# Background Image Overflows in Tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-tabhost

I am working on an application in which I am using 2 TabActivity Control. When I set the background Image of any tab it covers full screen, it even covers the tab control. However the tab control remains at the back of the image. This is really weird behavior. Anyone please help me out.

Here is the code for my Main Tab Control:\

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code for the tab who's background is being added:

**Tab1:**

```
public class FirstTab extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /* First Tab Content */
    TextView textView  =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    textView.setText("First Tab");
}
```

}

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:background="@drawable/lux">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Lux image shows up on full screen...I want it to show under the tab. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is background a 9-patch png ?

Comment: Then I recommend to use a 9-patch image, as it will scale to fit the container.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:background="@drawable/lux">
```

see that you have layoutSet height and width fill parent, make it wrap_content and keep lux image size very small to fit in tab, or make height and width in dp say 48dp/64dp/72dp/96dp